# Campaign Hierarchy in search layout?

Tags: campaign, hierarchy, nonprofit-starter-pack

Is it possible to show campaign hierarchy in the search layout?

Ideally I'd like the search layout to mimic the indentation that gives a visual representation of search layout on the campaign layout page.

in other words, I want this: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s184/sh/5a70439e-5e87-4bb2-8d7f-411b14bb6c29/009a40bcb6053f07d1415bb8c838321d

to look like this: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s184/sh/a44dca47-560a-46d6-a803-7f52ca65aa77/08eb511a68f13ecb8e8798a433972c51

So far i've only figured out how to add fields the the search layout.

Answer (score 1):

No, the campaign hierarchy is a unique "view" in Salesforce and not customizable or embeddable in a layout. Search layouts only include fields from the object.

Comment: You could create a list button that takes you to a Visualforce page, where multiple hierarchies are displayed.